# Django OAuth Toolkit - Only admin users issue

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, oauth, django-oauth-toolkit

I'm implementing OAuth in my Django Rest Framework backend with Django OAuth Toolkit so I can grant access (via authorization code) to Google Actions so when my users trigger an action, my backend can search the user resources and send a specific MQTT message.

I have already set up the flow correctly, but the problem I'm facing is that when the authentication form is presented by Django OAuth Toolkit, it only allows my admin users to log in. How can I give any user in my DB the possibility to retrieve an access token?

**Edit**

It looks like this is not a Django OAuth Toolkit issue, to login the user must have is_staff flag = True in order to grant access to OAuth applications. Any workaround or advice?

Comment: I cant seem to replicate this issue. can you open a proper issue on github